# Docker images upward compatibilty

Tags: image, docker, compatibility

I back up regularly my images in case docker hub stops providing some of them (like Debian-Stretch for instance). 
Should I be concerned about compatibility of those backups with new versions of docker? Should I 'update' them from time to time?

Answer (score 0):

Docker Images are independent of the docker version installed on the server. It is a program that performs operating-system-level virtualization. You can deploy an image of any version on a particular docker.

Comment: OK, so no risk of deprecation. However , what about removal of some images on docker hub ?

Comment: maintainers delete their images from docker hub when it gets deprecated